# Jquery datepicker control is not working inside child control of master page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, jquery-ui-datepicker

Jquery datepicker is working in normal webpage but not with master page concept.It's throwing error saying "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'".

Tried following approaches but no luck.

1st Approach:

```
$('#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker();
```

2nd Approach:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

3rd Approach: 
Placed jquery script files in master page and datepicker code between script tag inside content placeholder like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker();
</script>
```

Please suggest other approaches to make it work.

Comment: have you referenced javascript file for jquery ui in your html code? Check if the jquery files are accessible when open page source in browser

Comment: @AksheyBhat Yes. Gave all required jquery references.

Comment: The src path for jquery files may be incorrect for master page. Check if the jquery file links work in browser

Comment: @AksheyBhat : If path is not accessible then it should give error at `$` itself. But other jquery code is working fine except this `datepicker`.

Comment: have you checked for jquery ui javascript file? is it accessible?

Comment: @AksheyBhat yes, we are able to see it in browser.

Comment: also check if you have referred these jquery files before you are calling the datepicker function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121619/discussion-between-sandeep-kushwah-and-akshey-bhat).